# Qual a origem de «Velho do Restelo»?

Tags: significado, etimologia

O personagem [Velho do Restelo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velho_do_Restelo), dos Lusíadas, é muito conhecido e citado metaforicamente. No entanto, pairou-me a seguinte dúvida: por qual motivo Camões decidiu chamá-lo assim?

A definição de restelo (ou [rastelo](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/rastelo)) não me parece muito intuitiva para deduzir a resposta a esta pergunta. Alguém sabe o real significado, implícito ou não, desse nome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade Camões chama-lhe apenas [«velho d'aspeito venerando»](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velho_do_Restelo). A palavra *Restelo* não aparece sequer uma vez nos Lusíadas. Mas o velho proferiu o seu célebre discurso na partida de Vasco da Gama para a Índia, que nós sabemos ter acontecido na antiga praia do Restelo. E é por essa razão que autores posteriores o apelidaram de *Velho do Restelo*.

*Restelo* era ao tempo de Vasco da Gama o [nome da zona hoje conhecida por Belém](http://www.mosteirojeronimos.pt/pt/index.php?s=white&pid=188), em Lisboa. A mudança do nome deveu-se à construção no local do [Mosteiro de Santa Maria de Belém, mais conhecido por Mosteiro dos Jerónimos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosteiro_dos_Jer%C3%B3nimos), mas o nome *Restelo* sobrevive um pouco mais a poente no atual bairro com esse nome. Uma variante antiga no nome é *Rastello* [(Damião de Góis (1502-74), *Cronica de D. Manuel*)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uKtZhM29d9oC&pg=PA645&dq=rastello&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE1I627pXMAhXMvRoKHRP2Bww4FBDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&q=rastello&f=false), e foi sugerido que na sua origem estivesse o [rastelo](http://www.aulete.com.br/rastelo), uma espécie de pente de ferro para trabalhar [(rastelar)](http://www.aulete.com.br/rastelar) o linho [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restelo).

Nos Lusíadas o «velho de aspeito venerando» surge entre a multidão que se despede dos marinheiros de partida para a Índia, e começa famosamente o seu discurso com

> Ó glória de mandar, ó vã cobiça
>   Desta vaidade a quem chamamos Fama

e continua com uma crítica veemente à expedição e a aventuras ultramarinas em geral, prevendo calamidades para os marinheiros e o reino. Daí ele se ter tornado num símbolo do pessimismo e conservadorismo. No entanto isto parece ter acontecido tardiamente. Procurei no Google Books, e parece ser em meados do século XIX que começam a aparecer comentários políticos e sociais em torno da personagem. O primeiro exemplo que encontrei é de 1853 no [*Estudo moral e politico sobre Os Lusiadas* de José Silvestre Ribeiro (p. 132; grafia original e ênfase minha em todas as citações seguintes):](http://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5QaflTNIjxx6cDrug2TQWbaVsKF15pO9SyG6LZCCYic2zAiLAlibnA-FiubmEt0qLS7PsCu2nPiQDA-5SUWY35zpBoaNnxwmd5DEh0EIDL1CVUVHP2ErjqDrtQOz3buCRdEKJIImR-L6ZAj_UjVi-gZh8LZtGT9O5TNGkqeiYzaBsRYu5Zp73V5o549Dk9r5uXYeyZfG95O6cr6CxSkoF6Fi6jC3E226pryK8IEQXTCtptIsCS5rQ0XCnRCugje9drpncBcFykPXOcgW6pHVciAv_RJW-YBNPz8CsjrYB7fMZASrXR7Y)

> E o caso he que por todo o Reino se pensava do mesmo modo por que se exprimia na praia o ***velho de aspeito venerando*** […] Os vaticínios do velho verificarão-se, desgraçadamente, pelo andar dos tempos, pois que Portugal só conserva as gloriosas recordações […]

A primeira referência ao velho desligada de uma discussão dos Lusíadas, encontrei-a num debate acerca da marinha brasileira nos [*Annaes do Parlamento Brazileiro* de 1879](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_SNXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22velho%20dos%20lus%C3%ADadas%22&dq=%22velho%20dos%20lus%C3%ADadas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH5u7O9pPMAhUBcRQKHSEND0YQ6AEIKjAB), onde ele é referido por *velho dos Lusíadas*:

> As condições da guerra hoje podem não ser as mesmas que eram no tempo em que o ***velho dos Lusíadas*** gritava vendo afastar-se da praia os navios portuguezes :
>   Ah maldito o primeiro que no mundo
>   Nas ondas vela pôz em secco lenho

É do ano seguinte, 1880, a primeira ocorrência que encontrei da expressão *Velho do Restelo*, na [*História de Portugal* de Joaquim Pedro de Oliveira Martins:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZHkNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22velho%20do%20restello%22&dq=%22velho%20do%20restello%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY1c7n85PMAhUGNxQKHa7TBWoQ6AEIOjAF)

> Camões fulminava, pela bocca do ***velho do Restello***, os que arrastavam Portugal para o mar ; como Plutarcho tambem condemnou Themistocles por ter lançado os gregos no caminho das emprezas maritimas.

E finalmente, encontrei o primeiro uso metafórico da expressão numa introdução a um projeto de Constituição apresentado por José Soares da Cunha e Costa ao Parlamento português em 1911 [(*As Constituintes de 1911 e os seus Deputados; obra composta e dirigida por um antigo official da Secretaria do Parlamento*, p. 437):](http://purl.pt/16428/3/#/446)

> A hora, porém, não é de desalentos, é de esperanças, e não serei eu o ***Velho do Restello*** n'esta data que a tanta gente enche de orgulho, de commoção e de fé !

Comment: Muito obrigado, Jacinto! Faltam-me esses conhecimentos básicos sobre os nomes dos lugares.

Comment: Não é de admirar. Deve haver milhares de nomes de lugares que eu não sei.

Comment: Tem conhecimento se o Camões chega a referir em alguma parte da obra onde fica o Restelo? Nunca li Os Lusíadas, mas pode ser que esteja lá essa informação.

Comment: @felipe.zkn "Restelo" não aparece nos Lusíadas. Mas é sabido donde é que Vasco da Gama partiu.

Comment: Foge do âmbito deste site, mas gostava muito de saber quando e por quem o personagem começou a ser conhecido como Velho do Restelo.

Comment: Apurar a origem duma expressão está, no meu entender, no âmbito do site. Mas eu não consegui apurar muito. Reeditei a resposta completamente, incorporando tudo de relevante que descobri.

Comment: Jacinto, encontrei [uma obra](http://catalogolx.cm-lisboa.pt/ipac20/ipac.jsp?session=144917AN6912J.97577&profile=rbml&source=~!rbml&view=subscriptionsummary&uri=full=3100024~!4338~!3&ri=1&aspect=subtab11&menu=home&ipp=20&spp=20&staffonly=&term=velho+do+restelo&index=.GW&uindex=&aspect=subtab11&menu=search&ri=1), de 1898, com o título de **_O velho do Restello_**, de autoria de Teophilo Braga.

Comment: @felipe.zkn Expandi a resposta com várias citações. Consegui encontrar ocorrências de *velho do Restelo* mais antigas que a do Teophilo Braga, mas não muito mais. Parece ser uma expressão relativamente recente mesmo.